# No data in template when resolving in angularjs (ui.router)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got no HTML output but when I `console.log` the result of my `$http.get` I've got the object I want to have. Can someone explain me how to get the data from `$http.get` in my template?

```
.state('secure/contacts',{
                url:'/secure/contacts',
                template:"Contacts: {{contacts  | json}}",
                resolve:{
                    contacts : function(UserService){
                        return UserService.all();
                    }
                },
                controller:function($scope,contacts){

                    $scope.contacts = contacts;


                }
            })

.service('UserService',function($http){
   return {
       get:get,
       all:all
    } ;

    function all(){
        $http.get('/api/contacts').then(function(payload){
            console.log(payload.data);
            return payload.data;
        });
    }

    function get(id){
        return $http.get('/api/user/'+id).then(function(payload){
            return payload.data;
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `all()` function doesn't return anything.

Replace

```
function all(){
    $http.get('/api/contacts').then(function(payload){
        console.log(payload.data);
        return payload.data;
    });
}
```

by

```
function all(){
    return $http.get('/api/contacts').then(function(payload){
        console.log(payload.data);
        return payload.data;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return promise (`return $http.get(...)`) from `UserService.all` method:

```
function all() {
    return $http.get('/api/contacts').then(function(payload) {
        return payload.data;
    });
}
```